# Javascript class constructor not setting class variables as expected

Tags: javascript, class-constructors

I'm trying to set API endpoints by environment in a javascript helper class I'm using to pull data into my react app. It looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

class QueryHelper {
    endpoints;
    SupportEndpoint;
    MemberEndpoint;

    constructor() {
        debugger
        // get the endpoints set
        fetch('/environment')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.endpoints = data) // set the endpoints var with the json payload with all the endpoint and env data
            .then(() => {
                this.SupportEndpoint = this.endpoints.supportBaseUrl;
                this.MemberEndpoint = this.endpoints.memberBaseUrl;
            });
    }

    
    async fetchData(resource) {
        const resp = await axios.get(this.SupportEndpoint + '/' + resource);
        return resp.data;
    }
}

export default QueryHelper;
```

It would get used like this:

```
let helper = new QueryHelper();
helper.fetchData('MemberProfile')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(//do some other stuff);
```

When I hit the breakpoint, I can step through the constructor and the various endpoints seem to be getting set as expected. But when the `fetchData` method is called, the `SupportEndpoint` (and any other endpoint) is `undefined` and the ajax call fails with a 404.

Comment: `fetch` is an asynchronous operation and returns a promise, so you need to wait for it to complete. Not sure why you use axios and fetch in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is asynchronously setting those props. It’s fine to wait till `fetch("/environment")`  resolve then call `helper.fetchData()`, but if you call it too soon after instantiation, then it fails.

You need some mechanism to ensure the helper `isRready`.

```js
function defer() {
    let resolve, reject;
    const promise = new Promise((r, j) => {
        resolve = r;
        reject = j;
    });
    return { resolve, reject, promise };
}

class QueryHelper {
    endpoints;
    SupportEndpoint;
    MemberEndpoint;

    _isReady;
    _d;
    get isReady() {
        if (this._isReady) return Promise.resolve(true);
        if (!this._d) {
            this._d = defer();
        }
        return this._d.promise;
    }

    constructor() {
        fetch('/environment')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.endpoints = data) // set the endpoints var with the json payload with all the endpoint and env data
            .then(() => {
                this.SupportEndpoint = this.endpoints.supportBaseUrl;
                this.MemberEndpoint = this.endpoints.memberBaseUrl;
                this._isReady = true;
                if (this._d && this._d.resolve) this._d.resolve(true);
            });
    }

    
    async fetchData(resource) {
        await this.isReady;
        const resp = await axios.get(this.SupportEndpoint + '/' + resource);
        return resp.data;
    }
}
```